# Sending response to generated session

Tags: android, express, express-session

I'm wiriting my application in Android, but i don't know how to send response only to device whos generated session with special ID in express-session. For example, i have 3 phones and click at the same time button login with difference data in pools, all 3 devices captured the same object instead of 3 different destined ( first response object from express was caught by 3 devices rest 2 object ignored, i want to sent object every one of them ).

```
....
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');



var app = express();


app.use(session({
secret: 'DFGDFG',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized:false,
 genid:function(req){
     return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(uuid.v1()).update(crypto.randomBytes(256)).digest("hex");
 },
}));


app.post('/login', (request,response)=> {

var post_data = request.body;

request.session.user = post_data.user;
request.session.password = post_data.password;

if(err){
console.log("error");
}
else{

var db= client.db('test');
db.collection('object').findOne({'user':request.session.user}, function(error,user){
   if(user.password == request.session.password){
request.session.amount  = user.amount; // if password was correct, sending amount account
   console.log('Success');
   res.send(request.session.amount);

}
else{
 console.log('Password invalid');
}

}




});
```

Comment: But still captured the same, I have (user1,200), (user2,300) , (user3,400), when i clicked at the same time button login in these devices with 3 different user data - all captured (user1,200) :/

Comment: 3 Devices , i put in first ( user1, password) , second(user2,password), third(user3,password) and clicked all together Login, express-session send first response ( user1,200(amount)), and this only one response was caught by 3 devices , another (user2,200) , (user3 400) nope and i had incorrect data

Comment: I think, one' s session cannot send to other, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28790024/11343720

Comment: It's little weird for me, I set sending delay response about 2 sec. And when i clicked togheter 3 devices in a similar time with different User and password, they caught only first object from response despite the different session :/

Comment: Please add your result.