# How to insert a user's id into a separate collection in Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two models, one that holds the user and one that holds their text(Blog). I simply want to append the user's id every time they post their text so I can later go ahead and query for my own use.

This is what I have tried doing but nothing happens. Do we need to use req.body.user_id? Why is req.session.user not working(not being added along with the new instance of Blog on save) when I intentionally made it carry the user's id

```
router.route("/blog/add").post((req, res) => {

    // Retrieve the uid form the user
    // Save uid to the db along with the whole Blog instance
    let blog = new Blog({  
        user_blog: req.body.user_blog,
        createdAt: req.body.createdAt,
        date: req.body.date,
        user_id: req.session.user //Not working even though it holds the id already 
    });
    blog.save()
        .then(blog => {
            res.status(200).json({
              message: "Blog saved succeccfully"
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Failed to save users blog");
            }); 
    });
```

Schema Blog

```
let Blog = new Schema({
    user_blog: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    date: {           
        type: String,
        default: moment(new Date()).format("MMM Do YY, HH:mm")
    },
    user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId // This will be the users own id
    }
}, { collection: "users_blogs" });
```

The user_id is not being appended, why?

Comment: does the user have to be authenticated to post blogs ? there are a million ways to do what you want and you don't have to append the id anywhere.

Comment: @C.Gochev The user does have to be authenticated. When the user signs in, I want to obtain only their posts and output it.

Comment: So I'm assuming you use middleware to authenticate your users?

Comment: i do use middleware for authentication.

Comment: So I already have most of the code written. There is a sign in and register and in order to post you do need to be authenticated or logged in to your account. I am just having trouble with this issue at the moment.

Comment: @Unbreachable Can you add your middleware code as well?

Comment: then in your middleware when you find the user assign it to `req` like this `req.user = user` (user coming from your query) and then you can simply use `req.user.user_id` in the handler

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: Are you using cookies to store the session_id? Without those I don't see a way to get the user_id from the middleware

Comment: I am using cookies and sessions, yes

Comment: I use socket.io to get the cookie

Comment: Okay so here's the deal, whenever I sign in to an account I can see that accounts ID by console.log(req.session.user). All I am trying to do is add this users id to every new post they make so i can later use it for something else.

Comment: In your middleware you'll need to access the cookie and use it to retrieve the user associated with it. Once you have that user, you can assign it to `req.user` and pass the request along. Your route that creates posts can then access the user_id from your request.

Comment: If you don't want to do that, you can store the user_id after the user logs in with local storage on the front end and pass the user_id in through req.body or req.params.

Comment: Okay, correct me if I am wrong but I think you're confused. I can access their sessionid or personal id. I am doing that by req.session.user, this is how I am accessing their id(which I think it's the right way). The problem now is me implementing it to their blog every time they post.

Comment: `req.session.user` is assigned only in the login route correct?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Assigning the user_id to `req.session.user` won't be of much use at that point. The request you're assigning it to gets destroyed after the response is sent back to the front end. Once that happens, `req.session.user` is no longer defined which is why you weren't able to get the user_id where you create the blog.

Comment: I don't think so because the session is stored in the server so it will be alive until the cookie is destroyed or time runs out. As I stated earlier, I am able to always see it through res.send(req.session.user) and it outputs the id. At that point I am trying to store it with their posts.

Comment: Yes the session is stored on the server, but if I understand correctly, a session that is stored on the server needs to be assigned to the req by the middleware. Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28789857/how-is-the-express-req-session-object-persisted) for a better explanation.

Comment: I clearly understand that. Look back at what I have under the Login route.  req.session.user = user.id; // This is where I get the id

Comment: Your two middlewares do the same thing you only need one :) try to assign req.session.user to req.user in the middleware then access it but if there is something in req.session.user you wouldn't even need to do that. try to log what you get in the middleware and you will find your problem

Comment: Thanks but are you sure? I have the redirectHome for the login route, if they are signed in then I don't want them to see the log in/register pages, that's why I have it. Also, that is what I have been trying to say this whole time, sorry if I wasn't clear, but req.session.user already has the user's id. It had it this whole time. I am specifically having trouble with how to implement the user's id with the user's post whenever the user makes a new post.